# window.open lnk not getting rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used following javascript function on button click:

```
function searchItems() {

            alert("Called");

            window.open('' + <%#VMPath %>"/SearchItems.aspx?Value=" + $("#ctl00_txtSearch").val() + '', '_self');

        }
```

But this function is showing me following error

[image]

I tried with different single quote / double quote sequences but it didnt worked.

I wanted to just have simple :

```
window.open("url","_self");
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with concatination. You could make "<%#VMPath %>" a part of the string from the beginning:

```
window.open('<%#VMPath %>/SearchItems.aspx?Value=' + $("#ctl00_txtSearch").val(), '_self');
```

Comment: strange... error has gone by this but its not applying _self ... what can be the issue??? without self its redering page to another tab.. i want to open it in same tab but self is not getting applied

Comment: use "window.location.href" instead. As in: window.location.href = '<%#VMPath %>/SearchItems.aspx?Value=' + $("#ctl00_txtSearch").val();

Comment: ohh... simply gr8 ... Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

You missed a `+` after `<%#VMPath %>`, so it didnt concat properly.

Use this:

```
window.open('' + <%#VMPath %> + "/SearchItems.aspx?Value=" + $("#ctl00_txtSearch").val() + '', '_self');
```

Comment: "+" messed up all the url as : window.open('' + http://www.whatever.com/DC + "/SearchItems.aspx?Value=" + $("#ctl00_txtSearch").val() + '', '_self');

Comment: @CuteChild You are using `+` in the wrong way in the code that you mentioned in the comment above. Do it this way: `window.open("whatever.com/DC/SearchItems.aspx?Value=" + $("#ctl00_txtSearch").val() + '', '_self');`. Why are you adding unnecessary empty strings?